# "In which shift are you today? or In which shift you are today?" which is correct?

Tags: questions, sentence-patterns

Out of these two sentence which is the right one are we supposed to say are you or you are when asking for a specific timeline that someone is present.

Comment: Whatever kind of question you are asking, you need to invert the subject and verb. _You are cold. Are you cold?_

Answer (score 1):

The second one is wrong. The first one is fine. However, the noun "shift" usually takes **on** rather than in.

Additionally, it's more common to hear

> Which shift are you **on** today.

Putting the on at the start, though perhaps more formal, sounds odd, and forced. It's not incorrect though.